# Rust equivalent of C++ namespace?

Tags: rust, module, namespaces

With C++ namespaces, I can put anything anywhere from any file, and at compile time they will "merge" into a single namespace. Thus, this file structure:

```cpp
/* src/main.cpp */
int main() {
    nsfoo::foo();
}
/******/

/* src/foo/function.cpp */
namespace foo {
    void foo(nsfoothing thing) {}
}
/******/

/* src/foo/structures.cpp */
namespace foo {
    struct nsfoothing {};

    void nsfooprocessthing(nsfoothing thing) {}
}
/******/
```

is equivalent to having a single file containing:

```cpp
/* src/main.cpp */
namespace nsfoo {
    struct nsfoothing {};
    void foo(nsfoothing thing) {}
    void nsfooprocessthing(nsfoothing thing) {}
}

int main() {
    nsfoo::foo();
}
/******/
```

or this file structure:

```cpp
/* src/main.cpp */
int main() {
    nsfoo:foo();
}
/******/

/* src/foo/foo.cpp */
namespace nsfoo {
    struct nsfoothing {};
    void foo(nsfoothing thing);
    void processnsfoothing(nsfoothing thing);
}
/******/
```

or this file:

```cpp
/* tmp/quickndirtytesting.cpp */
namespace foo {
    struct nsfoothing {};
}

namespace foo {
    void foo(nsfoothing thing) {}
    void processnsfoothing(nsfoothing thing) {}
}

int main() {
    nsfoo::foo();
}
/******/
```

Point being, there are basically no restrictions as to how I layout my "modules", with what I put in what file - they will all "merge" when compiling.

With Rust, I tried translating a thing that should work in C++:

```rs
/* src/main.rs */
mod mymod {
    struct Foo {}
}

mod mymod { // <-- the name `mymod` is defined multiple times. `mymod` must be defined only once in the type namespace of this module.
    struct Bar {}
}

fn main() {
    // Would reference mymod here, but it produced an error before I even get here.
}
/******/
```

and quickly found that my experience "placing anything anywhere in whatever file structure" with C++ namespaces doesn't quite work the same in Rust. Ideally, I would like to have a structure similar to how I would have in C++:

```
.
└── src
    ├── main.rs
    └── mymod
        ├── agroupoffunctions.rs
        ├── structures.rs
        └── yetanothergroupoffunctions.rs
```

So I guess my question is, how do I make "partial namespaces" in Rust, similar to C++? If such a thing is not possible, how am I supposed to organize my data structures and functionalities?

Comment: The re-exporting technique described in kmdreko's answer is a very standard and idiomatic way to flatten a hierarchically organized implementation into a flat(ter) interface. Most non-trivial Rust code bases make heavy use of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rust does not have a mechanism like C++'s namespaces.

Rust's modules are the way to organize code, but they do not do any kind of automatic merging. If you want more nested files but access them in a flatter path, then you can re-export items from child modules into the parent module.

---

Silly example:

If you are writing code in `main.rs` and don't want to specify `plants::trees::Pine`, but rather want `plants::Pine` to work.

```
src/
- main.rs
- plants/
  - mod.rs
  - trees/
    - ...
  - ferns/
    - ...
  - grasses/
    - ...
```

Then you can re-export everything from `plants::trees` into `plants` in its `mod.rs`:

```
mod trees;
mod ferns;
mod grasses;

pub use trees::*; // <-- re-exports everything
pub use ferns::*;
pub use grasses::*;
```

Comment: Nitpick: "you can re-export items from child modules into the parent module" — It is also possible to re-export items from *any* module (or even other crates), not only child modules. (So, in principle you can make a module whose items are just as spread out as in C++ — you just have to mention all their locations in the module.)